# JavaScript regex pattern for numbers only and ignore backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, regex-negation

I am very new to regex and in researching for an answer found many cryptic answers, I hope someone here can lend a hand. I am validating an input field for MM/DD and am limiting the input to numbers only with

```
ng-pattern="/^0|[1-9]\d*$/"
```

The format we are using in the app is MM/YY, with the '/' automatically being entered with jQuery .keypress function.  For some reason the field validates fine until after the '/' and then it only validates the last two numbers.

Is there a pattern that will essentially ignore the '/' so the entire field can be validated for numbers only?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected regexp:

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/
```

It means `start` `2 integers` `slash` `2 integers` `end`